# Menu ul elements not showing below h1 and icon

Tags: html, css

I created a hamburger menu that only appears when the screen is smaller than 600px wide. When you click on the hamburger icon the list is displayed.
Problem: the menu covers the `h1` and the hamburger icon. I want the menu to be displayed below the icon and `h1` tag. I am trying to do what is similar to [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_mobile_navbar) page. [This](http://z1labs.com/projects/landingpage/) is the page I am trying to edit to show the menu when the hamburger menu is clicked (screen size must be 600px or less).

HTML of the menu:

```css
 header {
            margin: 1px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
    .icon {
            display: inline;
        }
    
        .fa-bars {
            color: white;
        }
    
        #navbar__list_2 {
            width: 100%;
            background: #000;
            height: auto;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            letter-spacing: 0;  
        }
    
        #navbar__list_2 li {
            list-style: none;
            display: block;
        }
    
        #navbar__list_2 li a {
            color: #fff;
            line-height: 50px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            text-decoration: none;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            margin-top: 0px;
            padding-left: 20px;
            padding-right: 20px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: block;
        }
    
        #navbar__list_2 li a:hover {
            background-color: #fff;
            color: #000;
        }
```

```html
 <header class="main__hero">
      <!-- replace list with hamburger icon when screen is smaller than 600px -->
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="menu()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg"></i>
      </a>
      <h1>Landing Page </h1>
    </header>
    <!-- vertical menu for screens smaller than 600px -->
    <ul id="navbar__list_2">
      <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section4">Section 4</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Remove property** `position: fixed; top: 0;` from ID  #navbar__list_2.
then Menu ul elements will show below h1 and icon

```css
 header {
            margin: 1px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
    .icon {
            display: inline;
        }
    
        .fa-bars {
            color: white;
        }
    
        #navbar__list_2 {
            width: 100%;
            background: #000;
            height: auto;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            letter-spacing: 0;  
        }
    
        #navbar__list_2 li {
            list-style: none;
            display: block;
        }
    
        #navbar__list_2 li a {
            color: #fff;
            line-height: 50px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            text-decoration: none;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            margin-top: 0px;
            padding-left: 20px;
            padding-right: 20px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: block;
        }
    
        #navbar__list_2 li a:hover {
            background-color: #fff;
            color: #000;
        }
```

```html
 <header class="main__hero">
      <!-- replace list with hamburger icon when screen is smaller than 600px -->
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="menu()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg"></i>
      </a>
      <h1>Landing Page </h1>
    </header>
    <!-- vertical menu for screens smaller than 600px -->
    <ul id="navbar__list_2">
      <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section4">Section 4</a></li>
    </ul>
```